# Problem with running a function in 2 threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, pthreads

I have written a program with a function that prints a character received as an argument continuously, and made 2 threads running that function. The program runs as intended and keeps printing 2 characters interlaced indefinitely. Here is the code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void* print_char(void* th_param) {
        char* ch = (char*)th_param;
        while(1)
                printf("%c", *ch);
        return NULL;
}
int main() {
        char* c1 = "a";
        char* c2 = "b";
        pthread_t th_id;
        pthread_create(&th_id, NULL, &print_char, (void*)c1);
        pthread_t th_id2;
        pthread_create(&th_id2, NULL, &print_char, (void*)c2);
        return 0;
}
```

Now I have to modify this program so the print function takes a number argument as well, and prints the character that number of times. What I try is this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Params {
        char* ch;
        int num;
};
void* print_char(void* th_param) {
        int i;
        struct Params* par = (struct Params*)th_param;
        for(i=0; i<par->num; i++) {
                printf("%s", par->ch);
        }
        return NULL;
}
int main() {
        struct Params* p1 = (struct Params*)malloc(sizeof(struct Params));
        p1->ch = "a"; p1->num = 5;
        struct Params* p2 = (struct Params*)malloc(sizeof(struct Params));
        p2->ch = "b"; p2->num = 10;
        pthread_t th_id;
        pthread_create(&th_id, NULL, &print_char, (void*)p1);
        pthread_t th_id2;
        pthread_create(&th_id2, NULL, &print_char, (void*)p2);
        while(1) {}
        return 0;
}
```

But to no avail. Doesn't print a single character, the cursor just stands there blinking doing nothing. I have tried tampering with the code for hours and nothing has worked.
Note that there's not a problem with the struct, because the program works if I remove the for loop and put `while(1)` instead, and prints the character given to `par->ch` infinite times again.

Comment: You are assigning a character to a pointer. ch is a pointer. Also "a" should be 'a' and "b" should be 'b'. As double quotes implies a string.

Comment: @RishabhHardas You are completely wrong. You have failed to consider that the two points you make, **taken together**, are perfectly fine.

Comment: Looking back at the comment, I agree with you! I should avoid hasty commenting! Thanks @EOF!

Comment: Code looks fine to me - except for missing `free()` statements.
You may also want to consider replacing `while(1) {}` with `pthread_join(th_id,NULL); pthread_join(th_id2,NULL);`.
I tried to run the code and it gave the following result: `aaaaabbbbbbbbbb`. Which platform did you try this on?

Comment: Please keep in mind that printf isn't necessarily thread-safe to begin with, unless the compiler lib explicitly makes such a guarantee.

Comment: @Lundin C11 draft standard n1570: *7.21.2 Streams 7 Each stream has an associated lock that is used to prevent data races when multiple
threads of execution access a stream, and to restrict the interleaving of stream operations
performed by multiple threads. Only one thread may hold this lock at a time. The lock is
reentrant: a single thread may hold the lock multiple times at a given time.*

Comment: @EOF Yeah but printf itself might not necessarily be thread-safe.

Comment: @Lundin That sounds like a ridiculous claim after my quotation. Can you back it up in any way at all? Also, [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09) does *explicitly* require `printf()` to be threadsafe.

Comment: @EOF In general, the C17 standard chapter 7.1.4. From §4: "The functions in the standard library are not guaranteed to be reentrant and may modify
objects with static or thread storage duration." After which the standard continues to name various requirements that functions should follow in order to make them thread-safe. It's quite ambivalent. And regardless, even if printf is thread-safe, that doesn't mean it will work as intended still. If you have multiple threads calling a thread-safe printf simultaneously, they might just partially finish their output before another one gets to run.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because of your while loop, `stdout` never get's flushed

Try this :

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct Params {

           char* ch;
           int num;
    };

    void* print_char(void* th_param) {
          int i;

          struct Params* par = (struct Params*)th_param;

          for(i=0; i<par->num; i++) {
                printf("%s", par->ch);
          }

          return NULL;
    }

    int main() {

    struct Params* p1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Params));
    p1->ch = "a"; p1->num = 5;

    struct Params* p2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Params));
    p2->ch = "b"; p2->num = 10;

    pthread_t th_id;
    pthread_create(&th_id, NULL, &print_char, p1);

    pthread_t th_id2;
    pthread_create(&th_id2, NULL, &print_char, p2);

    fflush(stdout);

    while(1) {;}

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is buffered I/O.

Your `main()`-function loops infinitely, so the process doesn't terminate properly (only by being killed via an external signal), so the `stdout`-buffer is never flushed by regular process termination.

Since `stdout` is line-buffered by default, and your `printf()`s don't contain any newlines, and the amount of characters you try to print is smaller than the I/O-buffer, your program never writes out the buffer, so nothing is printed.

One approach would be to add `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf()`s in your thread function, or include a `'\n'` in the output.

Another (more sane) approach would be to have `main()` *actually wait* for the threads to finish, and gracefully terminate when they are done:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Params {
        char* ch;
        int num;
};
void* print_char(void* th_param) {
        int i;
        struct Params* par = (struct Params*)th_param;
        for(i=0; i<par->num; i++) {
                printf("%s", par->ch);
        //fflush(stdout);
        }
        return NULL;
}
int main() {
        struct Params* p1 = (struct Params*)malloc(sizeof(struct Params));
        p1->ch = "a"; p1->num = 5;
        struct Params* p2 = (struct Params*)malloc(sizeof(struct Params));
        p2->ch = "b"; p2->num = 10;
        pthread_t th_id;
        pthread_create(&th_id, NULL, &print_char, (void*)p1);
        pthread_t th_id2;
        pthread_create(&th_id2, NULL, &print_char, (void*)p2);
        //while(1) {}
    pthread_join(th_id, NULL);
    pthread_join(th_id2, NULL);
    free(p1); //make LeakSanitizer happy, don't leak memory
    free(p2);
    puts(""); //one newline for command-line beautification
    fflush(stdout); //redundant after the puts(""), unless stdout is redirected to a non-interactive stream
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, using fflush did the job.
To answer the person who asked what platform I ran this on, I was running this on Linux terminal. This was the homework for my OS lab class and pthread_create is all they have taught us so far, pthread_join and more thread management stuff come in later sessions.